# Usage of tenure vs term

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to express someone has completed his tenure/term in office. What is the difference between the following phrases:

President Obama has successfully completed his tenure as president.

President Obama has successfully completed his term as president.

Is one more correct over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Term - a fixed or limited period for which something, e.g., office, imprisonment, or investment, lasts or is intended to last.

"the president is elected for a single four-year term"

---

Tenure - the holding of an office.

"his tenure of the premiership would be threatened"

---

I think the word you are looking for is "term."  A term is a fixed period of time, whereas tenure is not.  A president serves a four year term in office.  If a president serves two terms, his tenure could be said to have spanned 8 years.

Definitions sourced from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us

Answer (score 0):

> Take the **noun tenure** for the period of time a person holds a
>   position or office.

- [*term*](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/term) is used in a [limited or precise sense.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=term&searchmode=none)

> - Tenure from the [*Latin tenere*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tenure) means "to hold" and refers to the period of time a person works at a particular job or in an office.

Tenure's synonym : [*term of office*](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/term%20of%20office)